# Why is my function failing even though pure logic SCREAMS for it to work

Tags: python, python-3.x

So my function takes in a list and a target num and it is supposed to return a list [with the index of the first number in the given list which when added with the second number equals the target num, the index of the second number in the given list which when added with the first number it adds to equal the target num]

```
def two_sum(numbers, target):
    for num_1 in numbers:
        next_numbers = numbers[numbers.index(num_1) + 1:]
        for num_2 in next_numbers:
            if num_1 + num_2 == target:
                if num_1 != num_2:
                    a_list = [numbers.index(num_1), numbers.index(num_2)]
                    return a_list
                a_list = [numbers.index(num_1), next_numbers.index(num_2)]
                return a_list
```

Here are the tests:

```
Test.assert_equals(sorted(two_sum([1,2,3], 4)), [0,2])
Test.assert_equals(sorted(two_sum([1234,5678,9012], 14690)), [1,2])
Test.assert_equals(sorted(two_sum([2,2,3], 4)), [0,1])
```

It passed the first two tests as expected but then fails on the last one due to a duplicate of the number `2` so I fixed my code for it to have a variable `next_numbers` which is a list which contains the numbers after the first num then that way it doesn't interfere with the index of the first one if the numbers are the same, but for some reason the output for the last one is `[0, 0]`, and I literally can't figure out why, I have sat infront of the screen for the past 10min and I just can't figure why that is happening.

Comment: I understand your frustration, but expressing it in the title is not that productive. It seems that you understand to some level why the posted code doesn't work ("due to a duplicate of the number `2`"); if you want us to diagnose the code where you "fixed" this, you should show that actual code instead, rather than describing the changes. It's especially confusing because the code you do show, and imply is from before "fixing" it, still has such a `next_numbers` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the third example, we know `num_1 = 2 and num_2 = 2`. So we get in the first if statement. Since `num_1 == num_2`, we don't follow the nested if statement. So now we look at how we are creating a_list. The first one is fine, we use `numbers.index(num_1)` which returns 0 index of numbers. The second one is not fine. We are using the list we created above (which omits the index shift). As a result, the second 2 is at index 0 of the second list.

```
numbers = [2, 2, 3]
numbers_next = [2, 3]
```

When we call `list.index(2)`, both of the above will return 0. To combat this, you can keep track of the number of times shifted, and add it to your second index. Alternatively you can loop using indexes rather than elements, and add the two indexes of the for loops to get your second element.

```
        if num_1 + num_2 == target:
            if num_1 != num_2:
                a_list = [numbers.index(num_1), numbers.index(num_2)]
                return a_list
            a_list = [numbers.index(num_1), next_numbers.index(num_2)]
            return a_list
```

Comment: omg if I had looped `for i in len(numbers)` this would have been so much easier...smh

Comment: :) Yes, give it a shot that way. You would not need to create a second list. Hope you get the solution!

Answer (score 0):

- The original solution did not work, because index returns the first element that it finds in the list, so it will always return the first one.
- The fix you implemented for it is not working because you're mixing between the indexes of the 2 lists - that is the index of an element in next_numbers is not the index of this element in numbers.

A simple solution for this is to have a variable, which will record your current position in numbers:

```
for i in [0..len(numbers)] :
   for j in [i..len(numbers)] :
       if numbers[i] + numbers[j] == target :
            return [numbers[i], numbers[j]]
```